# Query to get metadata of partitions table is taking a lot of time in bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery

Query to get partition metadata for all the tables in a dataset took 40 seconds and sometimes this query run very slow Attaching is the screenshot.[image]

Comment: Hi Sachin, I queried the partition metadata at my end with the same query and did not face any latency issues. It seems that the high latency is specific to your project and would require further investigation. So, if you are seeing a high latency constantly, please create a new GCP support case if you have a [support plan](https://cloud.google.com/support/). Otherwise, you can open a new issue on the issue tracker under the [BigQuery component](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187149&template=1162659).

Comment: Also, please note that [`INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PARTITIONS`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/information-schema-tables#partitions_view) is a feature still in preview.